# iFrame issue in Visualforce Page: Uncaught DOM Exception - blocked a frame from accessing a cross-origin frame

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, lightning, iframe

I'm having an issue with a VisualForce page I'm putting a Lightning Component on. The component simply consists of an iFrame. When I try to use the site I want to use as the src for the iFrame, it doesn't load anything inside the frame and I'm getting this error in the console:

```
Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "https://login.tigerconnect.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
```

If I try with another site, it loads fine. Is this because of this known issue? https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000oH6CQAU

Here is my code:

Lightning App:

```
<aura:application extends="ltng:outApp" access="GLOBAL">
    <aura:dependency resource="c:TigerConnect"/>
</aura:application>
```

Visualforce Page:

```
<apex:page title="Communicate" sidebar="true" showHeader="true">
    <apex:includeLightning />
 
    <div id="tigerConnectComponent"></div>
 
    <script>
 
        $Lightning.use("c:TigerConnectApp", function() {
 
            $Lightning.createComponent("c:TigerConnect", {
 
            }, "tigerConnectComponent", function(component){
                console.log("Component was created.");
            });
 
        });
    </script>
</apex:page>
```

Aura Component:

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global" >
 
    <div style="height: 90vh; width:100%">
        <iframe src="{!$Label.c.TigerConnectURL}" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;"/>
    </div>
 
</aura:component>
```

Comment: can you please check this https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/192486/blocked-a-frame-with-origin-https-xxx-dev-ed-lightning-force-com-from-access

Comment: Is that something that would fix my problem? It looks like that question is about a VF page inside an iFrame, which is not what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is due to TigerConnect - they do not allow embeds.