# Communication between Lightning Component and Visualforce - DOMException

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components

I'm following the instructions on https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2017/01/lightning-visualforce-communication.html to send a message from an iframed VF page to a Lightning component. The problem is I'm getting a DOMException in the console when `postMessage` is firing.

I tried simplifying the code even more to make sure I didn't have any issues with hard-coded domains.

Here's the Javascript function on my VF Page:

```
function sendToLC() {
    window.parent.PostMessage("Saved");
}
```

And here's the function in my Lightning Component controller:

```
doInit : function(component) {
    window.addEventListener("message", function(event) {
        console.log(event.data);
}, false);
```

When `sendToLC` is fired, I get:

> LightningDemoRTCHange?id=aAr2F0000008at4SAA:13 Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "https://xxx--daniel--c.cs91.visual.force.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame.

I found [Communicating between Lightning component and VF Page](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/192394/communicating-between-lightning-component-and-vf-page), but I don't have development mode on for my user.

Comment: while posting the message, please update the second parameter as "*" and method name is postMessage not PostMessage (just heads up)

Comment: @KiranMachhewar your comment is the answer. Want to post it as an answer and I can accept it?

Comment: @DanielHoechst Added the answer, hoping it should help someone facing same error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please change the method name to postMessage and postMessage has a second parameter which you need to use. You can use wildcard or put the specific domain (later is better)